# Janusgraph with HBase backend, graph traversal is slow

Tags: performance, graph, hbase, gremlin, janusgraph

We are using Janusgraph with Hbase backend for storing large data lineage graphs. The basic usage is to find a node, then do an impact analysis by traversing all the nodes that are affected by this node (recursively).

The speed I am currently getting is about 620 edge traversals per second. I consider that quite slow.

Here is the gremlin query:

```
g.V().has('name', 'xxx').
repeat(
 outE('flows_into').dedup().inV()
).
until(
 or(
  outE('flows_into').count().is(0),
  cyclicPath()
 )
).
path().
unfold().
dedup().
group().by(label).by(count())
```

Here is our configuration/environment:

Janusgraph server 0.6.2

- RAM 32 GB
- CPU - enough

HBase 2.1.4

- 13 nodes
- 750 GB RAM on each node

The graph has around 4 million nodes and 5 million edges.

Is this speed normal? Is there way to make the query run faster? Would Cassandra be better for our usecase?

It is hard to find any statistics about Janusgraph performace.

Comment: Some older figures on JanusGraph + HBase are here, as well as some explanation about response times: https://yaaics.blogspot.com/2018/04/understanding-reponse-times-for-single.html   Scylladb as a backend would be faster, for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting blog post @HadoopMarc. Do you have any idea how much faster could Scylladb be? And do you have any knowledge about Scylladb vs Cassandra performance?

Comment: It is probably easier to discuss this in the discussions section of the JanusGraph gitrepo. It is not clear yet to me what the limiting factor is in your case: the storage backend roundtrip time between repeat loops, the JanusGraph Server configs (also try your query in the gremlin console!), the JanusGraph instance configs like the query.batch property, etc. Also be sure to include the output of the profile() step.

Comment: @HadoopMarc I have added it to the gitrepo and added all details. I would be very thankful if you could engage in the discussion there aswell - https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/discussions/3335.